# number of decreasing function from $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which satisfy $f(f(x))=1+x$

Tags: functions

> Total number of decreasing function from $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which satisfy $f(f(x))=1+x\;\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ From Inspection we have seen that $f(x)=ax+b$ is/are only function which satisfy

that functional equation.

So  Put $f(x) = ax+b$ in $f(f(x))=1+x\;,$ We get $af(x)+b=1+x$

So $a[ax+b]+b=1+x\Rightarrow a^2x+ab+b = 1+x$

Now Comparing Coefficients, We get $a^2=1$ and $ab+b=1$

So $a=\pm 1$ and $ab+b=0$

$\bullet\; $ If $a=1\,$ Then $\displaystyle b=\frac{1}{2}$ and $\bullet\; $ If $a=-1\;,$ Then $b-b=1$(Not Possible )

So function which satisfy the above functional equation  $\displaystyle f(x)=x+\frac{1}{2}\;,$

So Total no. of function is $0$

But I did not understand how can I prove that there are only linear functions which satisfy

above functional equations.

Help me

Thanks

Comment: I think that there exist other, highly pathological, functions satisfying this equation.

Comment: You changed $ab+b=1$ to $ab+b=0$

Comment: Thanks I have Edited My answer.

Comment: "... is/are only function which satisfy that functional equation.". You have proved that $f(x)=ax+b$ *isn't* a solution of functional equation.

Comment: If it is continuous, then there is a value of x with $f(x)=x$, so $f(f(x))=x$

Comment: If it is discontinuous, then its range does not include all of $\mathbb{R}$, so $f(f(x))=x+1$ is not always possible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$f(1+x) = f(f(f(x))) = f(x) + 1 > f(x)$, so $f$ is not decreasing.